# EF Core: Include to result in left join with not nullable foreign key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with EF Core Include resulting in a Inner Join with the included table, but I want to force a Left Join.

The background is I am working with a database where pretty much all fields/columns are not nullable.
It's a database based on Microsoft Dynamics Navision and it consistently uses empty strings instead of null values everywhere.

Now as such all properties on the EF Core Data Models are annotated with [Required] attribute.
But that means, when fetching data, if I Include a property that Foreign Key is [Required] and this leads EF to generate the query with INNER JOIN. I want to force a LEFT JOIN as the propertys foreign key is empty string sometimes and I wish to treat that as if it was null.

Example:

```
var webOrderHead = _dbContext.WebOrderHeads
                .Include(h => h.Customer)
                .Include(h => h.Currency)
                .FirstOrDefault(w => w.WebOrderId == webOrderId);
```

In the above the foreign key for Currency can be an empty string and when it is the query will return Default (null) even though there exists a matching row. I still want the matching WebOrderHead but with the property Currency = null, as would happen if the foreign key property was not marked [Required].
I already have null-checks for Currency later on when this property will be accessed.

(I am not the database architect and cannot change the database column datatypes to be nullable, as I would prefer it. I need to solve this within EF Core for my application)

Thanks //Jonas

Comment: Well, you can't change the database, but you also can't change EF Core rules which are simple - Required -> Inner Join, Optional -> Left Join. So the only wat to let EF Core do left outer join is to mark the relationship optional.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok but marking it as Optional will affect all submit forms where the model is used. I would have to do custom validation to make sure the data is filled out. Might also have other implications?

Comment: Sure it might have implications since you are tricking EF Core / not using it the way it is designed. But as I said, that's the only way to get left join. What about validations, use `IsRequired(false)` relationship fluent API - it is just for EF and has precedence over data annotations.

Comment: What I do is seed the table with a "none" record if it doesn't exist.  I then use that record's ID as the foreign key when making a new record where the foreign key isn't set.  Not sure if that helps you here, but during that seed you could take all your "" values and set them to the "none" record ID.  Going forward use the none in your logic.